# Sitecore Import Users Wizard - Browse button is not loading iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, sitecore, sitecore-speak-ui

We have a Sitecore 6.6 application for which we were asked to move the "Import users" functionality from Speak to Content Editor. While this works fine in Firefox, I see issues on Chrome on my Windows machine.
The "Upload file browse" button is not working
Clients have reported the issue on both FF and Chrome , if it is on a Mac.

Here is my initial analysis of the problem:
First - chrome for windows: Browse button click does not open explorer window. After debugging the issue we see that iframe is not loading in chrome.

On Inspect element the Iframe appears empty (Not loaded)

```
<iframe id="UploadFileFrame" width="100%" height="26px" style="position: relative; -moz-opacity:0; filter:alpha(opacity: 0); opacity: 0; z-index: 2;" src="/sitecore modules/shell/UI/Dialogs/UploadFile.aspx" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe>
```

Also on chrome(windows) I see that when I hit the back and next button on the wizard, the Iframe tag loads documents and browse button starts to work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: @Anton - thank you for the edits #copypaste struggles! ;)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what functionality you are talking about (is it custom?) and you also talk about SPEAK (which is a Sitecore 7+ thing)... but it could be an issue with the Flash uploader. Try setting `<setting name="Upload.Classic" value="true" />` and check.

Comment: Thanks Jammykam - yes it was custom to the level of sitecore 7 pieces were brought into sitecore 6.6 (for content editor), anyways we figured out the problem , it was a HTML container css setting overlsap problem.Resolved now.